# how to get FlyBase ID conversion table

Tags: identifiers, conversion

FlyBase uses systematic naming of genes, transcripts and proteins in a format `FBtypeNUMBER`. However, the numbers are not the same for genes and their products. For example gene `FBgn0259101` transcribes to `FBtr0299513` and translates to `FBpp0288787`.

On this [webpage](https://flybase.org/convert/id) users can conver individual IDs, but what If I need to convert practically whole transcriptome? Where can I get the full translation table?

Comment: On the right hand side you can upload file with IDs. You can  upload a file with the whole transcriptome and convert to polypeptide, you can also upload from gene > transcript and then once morte to polypeptide and merge the 2 tables yourself later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the web interface does not seem to link the full translation table, but it is available on their [ftp server](ftp://ftp.flybase.net) at `releases -> release_ID -> precomputed_files -> genes -> fbgn_fbtr_fbpp_fb_2019_06.tsv.gz`

For example, [this](ftp://ftp.flybase.net/releases/FB2019_06/precomputed_files/genes/fbgn_fbtr_fbpp_fb_2019_06.tsv.gz) is the latest (`FB2019_06`) translation table available.

Comment: took me like 20 minutes to find it, therefore I thought it might be worth sharing this with others.